# How compact, small and smart a fluid detector need to be communicate with external systems?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-nano

I like to build a fluid(liquid) level detector using Arduino that can send 2 types of information:

1. Status of the Fluid Container (Empty,Full or Below Required Level)
2. Location of Fluid Container

Now I like to know how small and compact such a fluid detector can be so that it can be placed in vessels, containers, tanks, etc. without causing any contamination to the fluid.
In addition, how can I interface this fluid detector with external systems like a smartphone app or cloud based app, etc.

What Arduino would i be using for the said purpose and why?

Comment: Size is inversely proportional to budget.

Comment: @Majenko Right... can you further elaborate with examples. Nowadays, there are so many ICs and compact nano-sized gadgets that are used even in human bodies as well. I agree what you said. But what feasibility is there for common commercial use? Thanks

Comment: The question you should be asking is not "how small can it be?" but "how small does it *need* to be?"

Comment: If you want small, you wouldn't use an Arduino, especially not an Uno.  You might use a QFN ATmega, but you'd be better off using an MCU integrated with your chosen radio transceiver.  Also, size has little to do with contamination, beyond the degree to which an admitted issue is a problem; you really should be looking for something made or encased in suitable materials.

Answer (score 1):

Your question should be broken into a minimum of two parts.

The first, regarding the sensor, can be addressed with at least one specific product, although there may be others of this nature. It is a teflon coated pressure sensitive strip placed into the holding container or tank. Teflon is a non-reactive plastic and will not contaminate the substance in the tank, unless you are measuring extraordinarily reactive chemical liquids. One example is 
[Chemical eTape](http://milonetech.com/products/chemical-etape-assembly) which is available in lengths from 130mm to 800mm.

[image]

This particular product is offered in three different interface types, all of which are acceptable to a properly configured Arduino.

The second portion of your question regarding the smartphone and type of Arduino is going to depend on how you plan to use the data you'll collect with the sensor. This aspect of the question is also extremely broad, as there are many solutions, including Blynk, SMS, WiFi and others.

You will want to "start small," and create a local Arduino-only interface, to ensure that you can properly code the sensor to present the results you require.

Once you have the data, you would then explore the many options available for distribution and dissemination.

Comment: Wonderful... I appreciate for the valuable detail you have added in your reply here. Now can you tell me what options would I use if I like to transfer the data (liquid level) to remote locations? As you mentioned about Bylink, SMS, WiFi, etc. What option would I go for if the liquid container is in New York and I am in Chicago? Moreover, the Chemical eTape does not detect the location (long. lat.) of the liquid container. How would I be able to detect the location of a certain liquid container, vessel or tank? Thanks

Comment: It would be more practical to consider to break off this question into other independent posts regarding both the communications and location aspects of your project. Prior to making a new set of posts, I would suggest to search here and the internet for "GPS Arduino" and "Arduino data over internet." Too many results to list in one comment, or even one answer. Please also check my answer if you feel it qualifies.